# Grid dont have data Kendo UI and AngularJS in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, kendo-ui, boilerplate

Im using KendoUI, AnduglarJS in ASP.NET MVC 4.
Im trying get data and show in grid, but my grid is not showing data.
Data is downloaded from db and I have they in js.

list.cshtml

```
<div class="panel panel-default" ng-controller="app.views.register.list as vm">


<div kendo-grid k-data-source="vm.registers" k-selectable="'row'"
         k-pageable='{ "refresh": true, "pageSizes": true }'
         k-on-change="vm.handleChange(kendoEvent)"
         k-columns='[
         { "field": "type", "title": "Typ"},
         { "field": "status", "title": "Status"},
         { "field": "ip", "title": "IP"},
         { "field": "description", "title": "Opis"},
         { "field": "createdDate", "title": "Data utworzenia", type: "datetime", format: "{0:d}"}         
           ]'>
    </div>

</div>
```

list.js

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module('app');

    var controllerId = 'app.views.register.list';
    app.controller(controllerId, [
        '$scope', '$location', 'abp.services.app.register',
        function ($scope, $location, registerService) {

            var vm = this;
            var localize = abp.localization.getSource('Ebok');
            //kendo.culture("en-EN");
            vm.handleChange = function (kendoEvent) {
                var grid = kendoEvent.sender;
                var selectedData = grid.dataItem(grid.select());
                var id = selectedData.id;

                vm.changeRegister(id);
            }
            vm.registers = new kendo.data.ObservableArray([]);
            registerService.getRegisters({ PageSize: 20 }).success(function (data) {
                vm.registers = new kendo.data.ObservableArray(data.registers);
            });
    }
    ]);
})();
```

In vm.registers I have data, here is example:

```
{"type":"dfdgf","status":"dfdrf","ip":"dfdf","description":"cdsdfsdfs666","createdDate":"2014-12-29T12:09:55.16","id":1}
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in configuration.
In file app.js I dont have one line 'kendo.directives'

```
var app = angular.module('app', [
        'ngAnimate',
        'ngSanitize',

        'ui.router',
        'ui.bootstrap',
        'ui.jq',

        'abp',
        'kendo.directives'
    ]);
```